# sort array of objects by two fields in php

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

i have an array of objects like this : http://pastebin.ca/3217309
i want to sort this array to objects with come first then others sort by date
currently I'm using this to sort array

```
function cmp($a, $b)
                   {
                       return strcmp($a->date, $b->date);
                   }

                   usort($data, "cmp");
```

and works good but it only sort array by date and i want to in ordered array objects with pin=1 come first then other objects come after pins.
i hope my question is clear,sorry for bad english !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to sort after an other criteria, you should just add the condition to your sort function:

```
if ($a->pin != $b->pin) return $a->pin == 1 ? -1 : 1;
```

this condition only applies for $items with unequal pin properties. Combine your old compare function with this one would result in the following

```
function cmp($a, $b) {
    if ($a->pin != $b->pin) return $a->pin == 1 ? -1 : 1;
    return strcmp($a->date, $b->date);
}
```

Comment: thanks you so much , another question can i add sort direction to it ? something like we do in mysql query : `ORDER BY date DESC` ?

Comment: sorry found the answer my self by switching `strcmp($a->date, $b->date)` with `strcmp($b->date, $a->date)`